# Rio clip ignores no-data setting?

Tags: python, rasterio, rio

I am using rio clip like this:

```
rio clip C:\\Users\\rit\\Documents\\Projects\\GG\\Data\\geonode.tif C:\\Users\\rit\\Documents\\Projects\\GG\\Data\\test.tif --like C:\\Users\\rit\\Documents\\Projects\\GG\\Data\\tmpHungary.tif'
```

The `tmpHungary.tif` file has a no data value of 255. However in the output `test.tif` file, even cells where tmpHungary.tif has nodata value are extracted.

How can I fix this?

Comment: From rio-clip's help: "Clips a raster using projected or geographic bounds." Nodata pixels are written to the output if they fall within the clip bounds. The output file's nodata attribute will match that of the input file. Are you looking for a different kind of operation?